# Magento 2.3 Inventory management with stock values coming from an outside system

Tags: php, magento, magento-2.3

I'm working on a project where I need to import stock figures into Magento once an hour from an outside system. I've got a script going to import the stock via SQL, and this works great:

```
INSERT INTO `cataloginventory_stock_item` 
    (`product_id`, `stock_id`, `qty`, `is_in_stock`, `manage_stock`, `use_config_manage_stock`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `qty` = VALUES(`qty`), `is_in_stock` = VALUES(`is_in_stock`)

INSERT INTO `inventory_source_item` 
    (`source_code`, `sku`, `quantity`, `status`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `quantity` = VALUES(`quantity`), `status` = VALUES(`status`)
```

However, since the introduction of Magento 2.3's new inventory management system, we're now running into an issue because it is now keeping a log in the table `inventory_reservation` which is used when calculating how much stock is available.
I am not sure what is the best practice here because I need the stock value to be managed from this outside system which also receives a feed of orders placed and adjusts stock accordingly, but Magento also does this so for every order stock is being deducted twice.

Is this best thing here to just empty the inventory_reservation table each time I run an import so Magento just thinks it has that amount in stock or am I missing something really obvious here in M2.3?